# fadeIn panel using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to **fadeIn a panel** form that I've made in Bootstrap 3. I've tried different methods but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1egdn3wx/).

This is my fade function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".anim" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could also do this

add .anim {display:none} to the css then show it in

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".anim" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1egdn3wx/1/

Comment: i've changed with your idea but the same, it is hidden, but won't fade in. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hide .anim in css so it can fade in.

```
.anim {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Don't know what else to tell you. Needs to be hidden in order to be revealed. http://jsfiddle.net/19htrres/

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that `fadeIn` method make the `.anim` elements opacity from the current to 1. 
So because the current opacity of .anim is 1, `fadeIn()` consider the fading done.

You should execute the `hide()` method before `fadeIn`. So your script will become as follow.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".anim" ).hide().fadeIn( "slow" );
});
```

Edit: this I've forked your fiddle with this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/diegolamonica/goetky8k/)